# Is it possible to do the code review if we select TFVC version control while creating the project in Azure DevOps Services?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfvc

Is it possible to do the code review if we select TFVC version control while creating the project ? I want the code review should be mandatory if my project is using TFVC.

For Git I know its possible. But unable to find it for the TFVC ? Does azure provide this option. or we have to use any third party tool ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=azure-devops

Comment: I want to make is mandatory step. This is optional as per the above link. The code checkin shouldnot work unless the code is reviewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: TFVC's code review capabilities are very limited and generally have never worked particularly well. Although the feature has a lot of room for improvement, Git has become the *de facto* version control system throughout the industry, and TFVC is no longer an area of focus for Microsoft (and hasn't been for at least 4 or 5 years).

If you want full-featured, well-supported code review workflows, your best bet is to migrate from TFVC to Git.

I'd be hard pressed to think of a good reason to start a new project using TFVC in 2021.

Official confirmation from Microsoft regarding the state of TFVC:

> TFVC is considered feature complete. Azure DevOps will maintain compatibility with TFVC, but Git will receive all future investment.

Ref: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops#:~:text=TFVC%20is%20considered%20feature%20complete,you%20need%20centralized%20version%20control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=TFVC%20is%20considered%20feature%20complete,you%20need%20centralized%20version%20control).

Comment: This answer could not be more wrong. TFVC is in focus and the short answer to OP is YES!

Comment: @BozhidarStoyneff I'm sorry, but you are incorrect. Here is official documentation confirming what I said: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops#:~:text=TFVC%20is%20considered%20feature%20complete,you%20need%20centralized%20version%20control.

Answer (score -2):

Of course, you can. The workflow is different from what GIT gives you but it's definitely possible. Check out this [MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=azure-devops) for top-level overview of Code Reviewing with TFVC but there are many other sources on the Internet.

You can request a review directly on your Pending Changes. However, you can [Suspend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/day-life-alm-developer-suspend-work-fix-bug-conduct-code-review?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=Suspend%20your%20current%20task%3A,currently%20in%20progress%20work%20item.) your work until it's being reviewed and work on something else in the meantime; then Resume your work, including your environment settings. This is one way to request a code review.

Another approach would be to create a Shelvset and request a code review on it. You can create a shelvset by shelving your Pending Changes directly or by suspending your work from the My Work section in Team Explorer. Then you can request a Code Review on the shelvset, amongst other things.

As for making it mandatory - you're looking for check-in policy. With it you can make the code review mandatory and more. See [this link](https://docs.devart.com/review-assistant/project-management/adding-code-review-policy-to-tfs-project.html) for details.

### NOTE

TFVC is by no means obsolete or abandoned. It is being fully supported and it is constantly being updated. IMHO, it is the best CENTRALIZED source control system out there. So if you want to stay centralized - i.e. corporate development and not open source - TFVC is your best bet. Working offline justification for GIT over TFVC is just not valid since more than 10 years ago - everything is online, including GIT.

Comment: For the sake of people who see this answer in the future: It is incorrect. Per Microsoft's documentation: *TFVC is considered feature complete. Azure DevOps will maintain compatibility with TFVC, but Git will receive all future investment.*.

Comment: @DanielMann, so GIT is feature-incomplete?!? It means there is no plan to create new features for TFVC, which makes sense given its maturity. MS were planning and was officially announced that there won't be subsequent version of the OS after Windows 10 but what do you know: [Windows 11](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11)

Comment: Yes, I'd say Git is feature-incomplete. For example, clone filtering isn't supported at the moment. Git is a third-party tool that is constantly being updated and improved, and so Microsoft has to continually invest in improving their Git-related tooling. TFVC, on the other hand, is Microsoft-owned and **has not** received a new feature in something like 7 years. There's plenty of room to improve TFVC (this question is an example of an area where it could be improved, i.e. a more PR-style code review workflow). However, Microsoft explicitly by word and by evidence **is not** investing in TFVC.

Comment: That's an opinion and not a fact or evidence. As stated above you can get your code reviewed, apply policies, etc. Also, PR != CRR !!! Moreover, PR is a concept for decentralized source control systems; TFVC is not decentralized so its workflows are different. Or maybe you're saying you're too lazy to learn new tricks ;) So no, there is no room for new feature as the Code Review feature already exists. But being supported and updated doesn't mean extended with new features, does it?

Comment: TFVC code review workflows only function within Visual Studio, thus only work for teams using Windows and Visual Studio. Azure DevOps is not a mono-platform tool anymore, which is why all major functionality has long since been migrated to the web UI. Except for many TFVC features, which continue to exist only within Visual Studio. So if you're a team doing Python development on Linux in TFVC... no code review functionality. And since TFVC is "feature complete", it will never be added. TFVC is **not** being updated. It's being **supported** (i.e. they aren't removing it).

Comment: One other point... I have worked closely with the Azure DevOps product team in the past. It's been stated in no uncertain terms by the actual people who work on the platform that TFVC is maintenance-only, which is born out by the documentation I provided. If you would like to refute this statement, please provide documentation of the last date that a new feature or substantive functionality update was added to TFVC.